# Twitter OAuth integration without HTTPS on my side

Tags: oauth, https, twitter-oauth, sha, sha2

Do I need HTTPS on my server with some SHA-2 certificate for Twitter OAuth integration?

Or may I simply send HTTPS requests to the Twitter API after receiving OAuth access token?